# Como executar um script python utilizando o VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel-vba, python-requests

Eu criei um projeto que consiste em enviar mensagens automáticas através da API do Telegram, fiz toda essa parte no Python e funciona perfeitamente, como mostro a seguir.

```
import requests
from datetime import date
import time

#TELEGRAM INFO
MyToken = "meuToken"
MyChatID = "-meuId"

#--------------------------- SEND TEXT TO TELEGRAM ---------------------------
DHoje = date.today() 
DHoje = DHoje.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
# MY TEXT
MyMsg = "Banco de Dados" + " " + DHoje
#SEND METHOD
SendMsg = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}".format(MyToken, MyChatID, MyMsg))
time.sleep(3)
```

A grande questão é que preciso executar esse script através de um código no VBA, e até consigo fazer isso, mas apesar da tela piscar e abrir rapidamente, nenhuma mensagem é enviada. Segue a parte do código do VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const PythonPath As String = """C:\meucaminho\Python36\python.exe"""
Public Const MyFilePath As String = """C:\meucaminho\MsgFileTelegram.py"""

Public Sub ChamarPython()

    Call VBA.Shell(PythonPath & " " & MyFilePath)

End Sub
```

Obs.: Quando rodo o código do python fora da macro do excel tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando executo o script pelo VBA nada. Alguma sugestão?
Obs.: Li bastante sobre o assunto e dei muito google, mas não consegui andar sozinho.

Comment: O usuário tem permissão na pasta/programa (`C:\meucaminho\MsgFileTelegram.py`)?

Comment: Oi, @PauloMarques, o usuário tem permissão sim. Fico a disposição pra qualquer outra dúvida.

Comment: Ao ivés de executar o python, tenta executar um batch (.bat) na mesma pasta. Este batch deve ter apenas os comandos `dir` e `pause`. Caso funcione, tente fazer com que o batch chame o python, mantenha o `pause`, pois caso gerar um erro, você conseguirá lê-lo.

Comment: @PauloMarques, fiz como você sugeriu e aconteceu o mesmo, a tela pisca mas o .bat não executa. Mas clicando no BAT roda normal. Não tenho certeza, mas me parece que o comando `Call` não tá passando o path do arquivo para o .exe do python/terminal.  Alguma ideia? Desde já agraço o empenho em ajudar.

Comment: Não conheco muito de VBA, mas creio que vc pode passar somente com `Shell(PythonPath & " " & MyFilePath)`, ou seja, retirando o `Call VBA.`

Comment: Infelizmente também não funcionou, aconteceu o mesmo problema. O Shell do Python abriu e fechou logo em seguida. Deu aquela piscada na tela, mas não rodou.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
RetVal = Shell(PythonPath & MyFilePath)
```

Ou se o script Python estiver no mesmo diretório da pasta de trabalho Excel, você pode tentar:

```
RetVal = Shell(PythonPath  & ActiveWorkBook.Path & "\MyFilePath)
```

Ainda um terceira alternativa...

```
Sub Python()

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonPath, MyFilePath As String

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonPath= "C:\meucaminho\Python36\python.exe"
    MyFilePath= "C:\meucaminho\MsgFileTelegram.py"

    objShell.Run PythonPath & MyFilePath

End Sub
```

Comment: Paulo, obrigado pela disposição em ajudar! Eu testei o que você sugeriu, nas duas primeiras opções precisei definir a `RetVal As Variant`, não sei se era sua ideia, mas não funcionou. A 3 sugestão também implementei e não consegui executar o Script Python, o shell abre e imediatamente fecha, não rodando o código do python.

Comment: Ok vou rever as opções e edito a resposta